# passing a rails variable into a js function

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, parameters

Apologies -- I'm a newbie using Ruby on Rails. Still a little confused about how it works.

Right now, in my view, under my scroller div, I have this code:

```
#scroller
 -@other_images.each do |img|
  .thumbnail_wrapper
    .thumbnail_image
      =image_tag img.image.url(:thumbnail), :class => 'button' , :onClick => "replaceImg(img.id);"
```

@other_images is a variable that holds all the thumbnail images I want to display on the page. Clicking on one will refresh a div elsewhere with its own big image.

the corresponding js function is:

```
:javascript
 function replaceImg(id){
  var url = '/images/refresh/' + id;
  new Ajax.Updater('content_image', url);
 }
```

This works if I just write in a valid url. But passing the param "id" into the js function does not work. I'm at a loss... what am I missing?

How do I pass this rails variable -- img --- into my js? It's just stuck in that loop.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
img.image.url(:thumbnail), :class => 'button' , :onClick => "replaceImg(#{img.id});"
```

The `#{...}` construct executes the ruby code within the curly brackets and replaces the entire construct with the result. Can be used anywhere you want to replace part of a string with some content from a ruby variable or method.

Comment: Thanks you answer helps me. but you can also use '<%= ... %>' this instead '#{...}'.

Answer (score 0):

Using

=image_tag img.image.url(:thumbnail), :class => 'button' , :onClick => "replaceImg('#{img.id}');"

can be a solution, or check the generated sourc code

Comment: thank you! but the key was to do it without the '' single quotes.

Comment: it's alright, but be sure your parameter is integer, because it can cause undefined variable error.